# Why does Android WebView reset JavaScript context on second page load?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am using an Android WebView with local data by first setting up a JavaScript environment and then loading web content that relies on the existence of the JavaScript environment:

**test.js:**

```
alert("test.js: type of window.myVar is: " + (typeof window.myVar));
window.myVar = {};
```

**test.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html><head>
<script>
alert("test.html: type of window.myVar is: " + (typeof window.myVar));
</script>
</head><body></body></html>
```

**loading procedure in Java:**

```
private void loadData() {
    _webView.loadUrl("javascript:" + testJSContent);
    _webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, testHTMLContent, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
}
```

The first time *loadData()* is triggered, *window.myVar* is available from the loaded HTML page, but *undefined* on any subsequent tries. Here is the alert output on three invokations:

-> loadData() called
*"test.js: type of window.myVar is: undefined"*
*"test.html: type of window.myVar is: object"*
-> loadData() called
*"test.js: type of window.myVar is: object"*
*"test.html: type of window.myVar is: undefined"*
-> loadData() called
*"test.js: type of window.myVar is: undefined"*
*"test.html: type of window.myVar is: undefined"*

Any ideas why the JavaScript object created by injection is only persistent until the second page load?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: afaik, every page loaded has its own javascript variables. If it wouldn't be like this, you could do XXS within your browser history...! it's not a matter of android-webview javascript in general, but maybe I misunderstood the problem

Comment: Good point indeed. But since setting up a JS context like this works for the first page load, do you know if there is any way to reset the WebView back to the initial state and re-enable JS injection?

Comment: something like myWebView.goBack()? I don't understand why you need to put javascript and html in two separated steps

Comment: This procedure is used within an Android SDK library where in-SDK JavaScript code has to be included into HTML markup retrieved from an external server.

Comment: I still don't understand the need of loading content (js, html or whatever) two times...can't you just merge them and load just once?

Comment: Unfortunately not, otherwise I would simply have done so. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should first load the html and after that page has fully loaded inject the javascript. Do it in OnPageFinished of the WebViewClient.

Comment: Already tried that, but won't work either. The page's JavaScript will execute before the injected code has run completely, causing ReferenceErrors.